# std::experimental::source_location implementation in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-c++-2017, std-source-location

A reasonably conforming version of `std::experimental::source_location` can be implemented in gcc with `__builtin_FILE()`, `__builtin_LINE()`, etc.  Do similar intrinsics exist in Visual Studio 2017?  Or is there any way to implement `std::experimental::source_location` in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: There are macros defined in VS `__FILE__`  `__LINE__` `__FUNCTION__`

Comment: Those aren't sufficient to implement `source_location`.  `__builtin_FILE()` returns the filename of the caller, not the raw location.  It has be implemented by the compiler, not the preprocessor like those macros can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment there is no way to properly implement source_location only by means of compiler, so you'll have to use preprocessor and macros like `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__FUNCTION__` to feed the location info into the data structure that stores them (what you call source_location).

Having said that, I really do share your pain.

I have been recently developing a small library that adds location data and some other information to the exceptions that get thrown, and there I had to end up with an ugly macro like `MY_THROW(Exception(args))` which basically just feeds the values obtained from the aforementioned macros into the function which throws an exception. As terribly-looking as it is, it seems to be the only working option so far.